# Using setInterval/clearInterval effectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am adding new features to my already developed application. I am trying to add an auto rendering functionality which automatically render some part of the screen after a certain time interval. I am using setInterval for this, everything is working fine.

My question is, how should I call the clearInterval(intervalId) function for all other events except one. Please consider an example:
Suppose I have some events related to current screen, and I want to start my setInterval only on ".myBtn" click and stop for all other events.

```
    var intervalId = 0;

    $(".myBtn").click(function(){
        intervalId = setInterval(function(){
          alert("execute something");
        }, 2000);  
    });

   $(".otherElm").click(function(){
      // some other stuff.
   });


   $(".otherElm1").click(function(){
      // some other stuff.
   });


   $(".otherElm2").click(function(){
      // some other stuff.
   });
```

For the above situation, **I know only one way to stop the interval i.e. to put "clearInterval(intervalId)" in every other event**.

**But, is there any other way to do this?**

*Hope I have put everything so that one can understand my question.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your comment - you have to put clearInterval(IntervalId) into all of the events that you require to stop the event. Is there a problem with doing this?

Edit:

Identify them all with a class - say elm. Once this is done, use $(".elm").click(clearinterval).

Comment: actually, there are so many elements on the screen which have events associated with them and in this case, I will have to put clearInterval in each of them :(

Comment: Then identify them all with a class, and use $(".elm").click(clearinterval)

Comment: Yes it is. Especially with the comment amendments.

Comment: Yes, you are right katspaugh, but his answer in his comment seems to be helpful solution if something else is not there.

Comment: Hey Schroedingers Cat... I have not found any other way except what you suggested in your comment... please edit your answer and put the same information from comment to answer area so that I can accept this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to do something like:

```
$(".myBtn").click(function(){
    setTimeout(someFunction,2000);  
});

var someFunction = function()
{
    // CODE HERE
    if(conditions for stopping function are not met){
        //Run function again
        setTimeout(someFunction, 2000);
    }
}
```

Although more code, I find it easier to manage, especially if you end up having a lot of intervalIDs to deal with.

Comment: The problem with this is the same - the "stop function conditions" need to be set in all other calls

Comment: Could add a global boolean (global to the app, that is) which is tested against in someFunction. If true (default), the function runs. If false. It stops. All of the "stop elements" on the page should be bound to a function that changes this boolean.

Comment: So you still need to put something in every event that wants to stop it. I agree that this is a neater solution than using intervals and stopping them, but the issue of not having to code into every other button is still there.

Answer (score -2):

```
setInterval("alert('negaweblog.wordpress.com')",1000);
```

1000 - 1 secs.

Every one second, it will alert 'negaweblog.wordpress.com'